# How to Refresh the Bindings on HomePageViewModel when some data has been changed in Navigated Page2

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, model-binding, binding-context

I have some property which I am using from Page2 in HomePageViewModel, When I navigate to Page2 I have changed that property and on coming back by doing NavigiationPop.

HomePage is not re-loaded/ refreshed at all as I have set the BindingContext in the constructor of HomePage, which is loaded only once.

The solution which is working for me is
Setting the BindingContext to the ViewModel on "onAppearing()", usually its not consider the best practice. But I also need to refresh the values which I have changed on Page2.

Looking forward for your valuable inputs and suggestions.

Also Pros/Cons of Setting the BindingContext in OnAppearing.

Thanks,

Hemant

Comment: are you using INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, they all can achieve the effect.

However if you want to reduce the CPU consumption of the program, then don't use the `onAppearing` method too much to refresh the page data.

Another method is that you can change the data of the model through **Delegate**/**Event**/**MessageCenter**.

You can refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174611/events-and-delegates-in-xamarin-forms-parent-and-child-pages/65177157#65177157) to know how to use *Delegate/Event/MessageCenter*.

Here I will give the sample by using **MessageCenter** to achieve that.

For example, the **TestViewModel** as follows:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string pagetitle;
    public string PageTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return pagetitle;
        }
        set
        {
            if (pagetitle != value)
            {
                pagetitle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then bind it in **FirstPage** as follows, and Subscribe MessageCenter inside it:

```
TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel();
BindingContext = testViewModel;

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", (sender) =>
{
    // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
    testViewModel.PageTitle = "Modified  Title";
});
```

Then in the **SecondPage**, when changing the data by sending message. When back to **FirstPage**, the View Will be updated.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
}
```