# Xamarin.Forms iOS DidReceiveNotificationResponse not called

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use local notifications in my Xamarin.Forms iOS application.

The notification is visible, but when I tap the notification, DidReceiveNotificationResponse is not called at all. The code that manages the authorization is not shown here but it is correct.

I have read all the posts here and elsewhere about this problem that seams to be related to a delegate issue (not assigned).

Here is my code:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Popup.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

        ...
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, System.Action completionHandler)
    {
        if (response.IsDefaultAction)
        {
            if (response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString("remainingTime")))
            {
                Locator.GetSharedInstance<IAlertDelayedService>().RaiseOpenAlertDelayedPopupEvent();
            }

        }
        completionHandler();
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, System.Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to register events with "+=".  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174611/events-and-delegates-in-xamarin-forms-parent-and-child-pages?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am not sure because this  [Xamarin iOS sample](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/0bc8046ca90cfe91684c85b6bdb12a114e3af793/ios12/RedGreenNotifications/AppDelegate.cs#L22) works perfectly

Comment: In the designer.cs file there are ACTION statements.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms, there is no designer.cs file, and I think that these action statements have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Then that is the issue.  The reason the sample work is the ACTION statements.  If you do not have the ACTION then you need to register the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in a Xamarin.Forms notification sample [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/LocalNotifications).
It uses a UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate [derived class](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/97d6825e2ba3aa64667695f3c43224c9171e51e5/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.iOS/iOSNotificationReceiver.cs#L7) to handle the received and tapped notifications.